# How to save .bmp image data to array and get RGB values of each pixel?

Tags: c

I am creating a program that can read a bmp image and calculate the percentage of red, blue and green color on it. I have searched a lot but haven't understood that from which byte does the image data exactly begins and how to get the RGB values of the pixels?

```
#include<stdio.h>

typedef struct {
unsigned int fileSize;
unsigned int offset;
unsigned int reserved;
char signature[2];
} BmpHeader;

typedef struct {
unsigned short bitDepth;
unsigned int compressedImageSize;
unsigned int compression;
unsigned int headerSize;
unsigned int height;
unsigned int horizontalResolution;
unsigned int importantColors;
unsigned int numColors;
unsigned short planeCount;
unsigned int verticalResolution;
unsigned int width;
} BmpImageInfo;

typedef struct {
unsigned char blue;
unsigned char green;
unsigned char red;
} Rgb;

int main(void) {
 BmpHeader header;
 BmpImageInfo info;



 char filename[40];
 printf("Enter file name : ");scanf("%s", filename);
 FILE *fp;
 fp = fopen(filename, "rb");
 fread(&header, 1, sizeof(BmpHeader), fp);
 fread(&info, 1, sizeof(BmpImageInfo), fp);

 printf("%u", info.height);





 getchar();
 return 0;

}
```

WHY AM I GETTING THE WRONG HEIGHT???

Comment: Consider using OpenCV

Comment: can you provide a link of its C interface

Comment: Its C interface is deprecated in favor of its C++ interface.  Its C++ interface requires minimal understanding of C++ (I learned C++ this fall through OpenCV).  Basically, you would just read the image with `imread` to create a Mat object from a file, then use the `at` method to access the rgb values.  There are multiple posts on StackOverflow on this.

Comment: Some would argue that is one significant downside to doing it that way. It is not a badge of honor to say "I can make it work, but don't understand how it does it..."

Comment: Look at http://paulbourke.net/dataformats/bmp/BITMAP.C and http://paulbourke.net/dataformats/bmp/BITMAP.H — particularly the `RGBQUAD` struct.

Comment: What value did you get and what did you expect? It may point out the problem. (Also, please do not use ALL CAPS.)

Comment: Just tell me that is the structure correct for a bmp file

Comment: I cannot tell you that. Did you copy all structure elements and their sizes correctly? What is `sizeof(int)` on your machine? What is its endianness? What is your default structure packing? (I suggest looking further into this last one first.)

Comment: Thanks everyone for your help but i figured it out myself

Comment: Do you people want the code??

Answer (score 3):

This link is to the wiki page that describes the .bmp image format. Things to note:

1. the .bmp image uses little endian for all fields
2. there are no gaps/filler between fields, so needs to be 
   treated as a char array and/or use #pragma pack 
   for the struct that describes the image.
   *I* prefer the char array method.
3. there is a field that describes the number of bits in each pixel.
   you will need that info when copying the data.
   also note that a 24bits per pixel image can have a 4th field for 
   opacity, so then each pixel would actually be 32 bits.

[**Here is the link**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format).

Comment: It's actually better to use a library, since implementing a complete bitmap handling interface should be a complex task. But still, no better answer could have been given. Hope you understand my broken english, I'm learning...

Comment: 4. The number of *bytes* per line of *pixels* is padded to a multiple of 4. For example, 5 pixels with a 3-byte RGB size are followed by 1 pad byte.